# How is a an Entity that has no persistent identity but managed is characterized in JPA?

Tags: jpa

Quoting from [JSR 317: JavaTM Persistence 2.0](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=317) page 76..

> An entity instance can be characterized as being new, managed,
>   detached, or removed.
>
> • A new entity instance has no persistent identity, and is not yet
>   associated with a persistence context.
>
> • A managed entity instance is an instance with a persistent identity
>   that is currently associated with a persistence context.
>
> • A detached entity instance is an instance with a persistent identity
>   that is not (or no longer) associated with a persistence context.
>
> • A removed entity instance is an instance with a persistent identity,
>   associated with a persistence context, that will be removed from the
>   database upon transaction commit.

Given I have the following Entity class..

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
    private long id;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String address;
    private String city;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    // Rest of the getters, setters..
}
```

In which characterization does an Entity instance fall in, if it does not have a persistent identity but is managed by an EntityManager?

For a concrete example, please see the comments in the method below:

```
public void insert(final Employee employee) {
    final EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerService.entityManager();
    entityManager.persist(employee);

    // The instance 'employee' is managed by the EntityManager but does not have a
    // persistent identity at this point?
    // In which characterization does an Entity instance fall in, at this point of execution?

    System.out.println(employee.getId()); // Will print 0

    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();

    System.out.println(employee.getId()); // Will print 1 with an empty DB..
    entityManager.close();
}
```

Is my understanding wrong that at the given point the entity is managed but has no persistent identity?

I do not think it is relevant, but here is my persistence.xml file..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="jpaExamples" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <class>biz.tugay.jpaExamples.model.Employee</class>
        <properties>
            <!-- Properties here.. -->
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

and this is what my EntityManagerService looks like..

```
package biz.tugay.jpaExamples.service;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public final class EntityManagerServiceByPersistenceUnitNameImpl implements EntityManagerService {

    private static EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    private EntityManagerServiceByPersistenceUnitNameImpl() {
        // Use the static method serviceForPersistenceUnitName to get an instance of this class!
    }

    public static EntityManagerService serviceForPersistenceUnitName(final String persistenceUnitName) {
        if (entityManagerFactory == null || entityManagerFactory.isOpen()) {
            entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(persistenceUnitName);
        }
        return new EntityManagerServiceByPersistenceUnitNameImpl();
    }

    @Override
    public EntityManager entityManager() {
        final EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        return entityManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void closeEntityManagerFactory() {
        entityManagerFactory.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: You persist an object WITHIN a transaction. Then it is managed! Your code has it being persisted outside a transaction so you would likely get an exception (depending on JPA provider)

Comment: @NeilStockton The method above works just fine, and I am not sure if your statement answers what I am asking. Thank you nevertheless.

Comment: As I said ... that depends on what your JPA provider (whichever it is) is doing there. Maybe it does "auto-commit" ? in which case it will be detached, depending on persistence context in use. Again you don't define adequate info, and the LOG for your JPA provider would explain way more

Comment: @NeilStockton I am using Hibernate in the above example and not getting any Exceptions. Are you suggessting that if auto-commit is on, the Entity immediatly gets a persistence identity? What if auto-commit is off?

Comment: @NeilStockton I added some additional statements in my insert method.

Comment: Just scroll a little bit in the specification, until the section about persists. It says: "A new entity instance becomes both managed and persistent by invoking the persist method on it".

Comment: @JBNizet But it does not have a persistent identity yet, does it?

Comment: No, but it will have one at the next flush. I agree with Neil that you shouldn't call persist outside of a transactio. Een if you do it inside, Hibernate might choose to defer the insertion (and thus the ID generation in that case). I'm not sure if the spec actually authorizes it, or if it's a Hibernate optimization. I usually use sequence which doesn't have the problem of needing to insert the entity to get its ID.

Comment: @JBNizet I see, so I should call .persist after calling begin on transaction.